# C++ program to output the month, day and year. It also determines if the year input is a leap year or not

Tags: c++, iostream

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    // declare the variable using int
    int month, day, year;

    cout << "Enter 1 to 12 for the month: ";
    cin >> month;
    cout << "Enter the day of the month: ";
    cin >> day;
    cout << "Enter the year: ";
    cin >> year;
    
    // using switch statement to add the days together
    switch (month)
    {
    case 1:
        cin >> day
            break;
    case 2:
        if ((year % 100 == 0) && year % 400 == 0) || (year % 4 == 0)
            day == 29 + 31;
        else
            day == 28 + 31;
        break;

    case 3:
        cin >> day + 31 + 30
            break;

    case 4:
        cin >> day + 31 + 31 + 30
            break;

    case 5:
        cin >> day + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31
            break;

    case 6:
        cin >> day + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31
            break;

    case 7:
        cin >> day + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31
            break;

    case 8:
        cin >> day + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30
            break;

    case 9:
        cin >> day + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 30

    case 10:
        cin >> day + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31
            break;

    case 11:
        cin >> day + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30
            break;

    case 12:
        cin >> day + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31
            break;
    }

    // output the month, the days added up, and the year. 
    // The output will also determine if the year is a leap year.


    cout << month << " " << day << " " << year;

}
```

I am struggling with figuring out this programming assignment for class. The assignment is to take input from the user data of month, day, and year. It also needs to determine if the year is a leap year. Not sure if using a list and char and ch would be easier to use as well.

An example: 10 12 2000. The program will output 286 days in the year since it was a leap year. This is in C++

// This program written to output the day, month, and year. It will be adding the days of the year
// and determining if the year input by the user is a leap year.

Comment: You are using `cin` wrong, you are using `==` incorrectly, and your check for leap years is also wrong.... I stopped looking at that point. Your compiler should tell you about the first two.

Comment: @ChrisMM I believe I found something and this worked.  
 int year;
 cout << "Enter the Year: ";
 cin >> year;

 if ((year % 4 == 0) && year % 100 != 0)
 cout << "It is a leap year";
 else if (year % 400 == 0)
  cout << "It is a leap year";
 else
  cout << "It is not a Leap Year";
 cout << endl;

Comment: From memory, `if ( year % 4 == 0 && ( year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0 ) )`, but your code (in the question) is not quite the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several syntax error, and it does not compile well.

1. You miss some `;` at the end of line of code.
2. Why you add `cin >>` in switch case? You already has `day` at the beginning.
3. Don't using `+` inside `cin`.
4. You don't check valid date (for example, 30 Feb or 31 April).

Your formula is also wrong. Think about it. If you are in month of 3/4, etc., you still check leap year.

Your output is also not show the leap year too.

Example of code.

```
int month, day, year;

    cout << "Enter 1 to 12 for the month: ";
    cin >> month;
    cout << "Enter the day of the day: ";
    cin >> day;
    cout << "Enter the year: ";
    cin >> year;

    bool leap_year = false;
    if ((year % 100 == 0) && (year % 400 == 0) || (year % 4 == 0)) leap_year = true;
    int day_of_feb = leap_year ? 29 : 28;
    
    // using switch statement to add the days together
    switch (month)
    {
    case 2:
        day += 31;
        break;
    case 3:
        day += (day_of_feb+31);
        break;
    case 4:
        day +=  31 + day_of_feb + 31;
        break;
    case 5:
        day += 30 + 31 + day_of_feb + 31;
            break;
    case 6:
        day += 31 + 30 + 31 + day_of_feb + 31;
            break;
    case 7:        
        day += 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + day_of_feb + 31;
            break;
    case 8:
        day += 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + day_of_feb + 31;
            break;
    case 9:
        day += 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + day_of_feb + 31;
        break;
    case 10:
        day += 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + day_of_feb + 31;
            break;
    case 11:
        day += 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + day_of_feb + 31;
            break;
    case 12:
        day += 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + day_of_feb + 31;
            break;
    }

    // output the month, the days added up, and the year. 
    // The output will also determine if the year is a leap year.


    cout << month << " " << day << " " << year;
```